# How to check class of actual active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have some carousel plugin. There is one element which have active class after one by one click. Also all of elements on carousel have classes `available` or `no_available`. Now i need to check this `active` element, and if it have class `available` do something and if is `no_available` do something else. This active class and element is changing after carousel click. So i do this, and i have only one condition respond, the first one. Can u help me?

```
carousel_images = $("#ajax-carousel"),
carousel_images_active_element = carousel_images.find("li.active");

carousel_controls_button.live('click', function(e){
    if (carousel_images_active_element.is('.available')){
        console.log('run_01');
        bottom_panel.fadeOut('fast');
    }
    else if (carousel_images_active_element.is('.no_available')){
        console.log('run_02');
    }
});
```

html

```
<ul>
   <li id="01" class="active no_available"></li>
   <li id="02" class="available"></li>
   <li id="03" class="available"></li>
   <li id="04" class="no_available"></li>
</ul>
```

Much thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i need to check this active element, and if it have class available do something and if is no_available do something else.

use [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

try this

```
carousel_controls_button.on('click', function(e){
   if (carousel_images_active_element.hasClass('available')){
     console.log('run_01');
     bottom_panel.fadeOut('fast');
   }
   else if (carousel_images_active_element.hasClass('no_available')){
    console.log('run_02');
 }
});
```

`live()` deprecated use `on()`

Comment: once again, hasClass have no respond from console :( even with `.on`

Comment: please log sumthing on click first.. checkwhen clicking .. the click function is called or not...`carousel_controls_button.on('click', function(e){  console.log('here')...` see if this prints here

Comment: this works bc i have more actions in this click event and everything is fine with those

Comment: just a head up, `hasClass()` takes a class name not the selector. So it will have to be `hasClass('available')` and not `hasClass('.available')`, i.e. without the `dot`. That might be the reason `hasClass()` is not working for you.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski can u please post your HTML

Comment: i think has class work check this jsbin.. http://jsbin.com/epacep/5/edit ...jsfiddle seems down.. :)..

Comment: i'm stupid, i'v set variables to 'hight' to parse this elements, thx

Answer (score 0):

Please use hasClass() function of jquery which let you know, whether specified element has the specified class.

For example if you want to know the following div element has a class "active", then please use it as follows

```
<div id="target-ele" class="class1 class2 active"></div>
```

$('target-ele').hasClass('active'); // this will return true as it has class "active"

```
<div id="target-ele" class="class1 class2 in-active"></div>
```

$('target-ele').hasClass('active'); // this will return false as it has no class "active"

so finally
if($('target-ele').hasClass('active'))
    do the functionality when there is active class
else
    do the functionality when there is no active class

Hope this accomodate your requirement :)

Comment: the construction is 
`<div class="class_01 active"></div>
 <div class="class_02"></div>`
and i told that before, hasClass is not working :(

Comment: oops! you have mentioned for the next answer :( . Any how you can checkout this!. In that case, you use it as follows $.each($('#target-ele').attr('class'),function(index,value){//Hopefully index or value will have the class name, so check by comparision and perform your functionality :) });